# What is an efficient SQL query to join to a double maximum in a sub query?

Tags: sql, join

Sorry the title is crap - I could not think of a better way to phrase it. This is my data structure:

```
Widget   WidgetTransition
------   ----------------
Id,      WidgetId,
...      TransitionTypeId,
         Cost,
         ...
```

I want a query that will give me a list of details for each widget along with the details of the **most expensive** (max WidgetTransition.Cost) transition. If a widget has two or more transitions that are 'tied' for the most expensive transition, the details of the **most recent** transition (max WidgetTransition.WidgetId) should be used. If the widget has no transitions, it should not appear in the results. This is the best that I could come up with:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Widget
JOIN   WidgetTransition
ON     WidgetTransition.WidgetId = Widget.Id
AND    WidgetTransition.Cost = (
       SELECT Max(MostExpensiveTransition.Cost)
       FROM   WidgetTransition MostExpensiveTransition
       WHERE  MostExpensiveTransition.WidgetId = Widget.Id
       )
```

This almost works, but has two problems.

- Doesn't deal with tied transitions properly. If a widget has two or more tied transitions, each transition will appear in the results, instead of the most recent.
- With large data sets, the query is sloooow. The Sybase database that I am running it on will do two table scans (WidgetTransition.Cost is not in the index) on WidgetTransition for each widget. Presumably one is for the join and one to find the max cost.

Is there a better way to write this query that fixes the tied problem and/or runs more efficiently? I want to avoid using T-SQL or a stored procedure.

Comment: For what version of SQL Server?  Analytics like ROW_NUMBER() are ANSI, supported by TSQL since SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a database product that supports ranking functions and common table expressions such as SQL Server 2005 and later (or recent versions of Sybase), you can do something like:

```
With Data As
    (
    Select WidgetId, TransitionTypeId
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By WidgetId 
                                Order By Cost Desc, WidgetId Desc ) As Rnk
    From WidgetTransition
    )
Select ...
From Widget As W
    Join Data As D
        On D.WidgetId = W.WidgetId
Where D.Rnk = 1
```

Comment: Wow. Common table expressions are awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the 'MaxValues' like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Widget
JOIN   WidgetTransition
ON     WidgetTransition.WidgetId = Widget.Id
JOIN   (SELECT MostExpensiveTransition.WidgetId, Max(MostExpensiveTransition.Cost) Cost
       FROM   WidgetTransition MostExpensiveTransition
       GROUP BY MostExpensiveTransition.WidgetId
       ) MaxValues
ON     MaxValues.WidgetId = Widget.Id
AND    WidgetTransition.Cost = MaxValues.Cost
```

I'm going from memory here as I don't have a sql database to play with at the moment, so sorry if it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this will do what you want.
Don't know about performance. You have to test that and try to figure out what indexes is helpful.

```
declare @Widget table (ID int)
declare @WidgetTransition table (WidgetID int, TransitionTypeID int, Cost int)

insert into @Widget values (1)
insert into @Widget values (2)
insert into @Widget values (3)

insert into @WidgetTransition values (1, 1, 1)
insert into @WidgetTransition values (1, 2, 2)
insert into @WidgetTransition values (2, 1, 2)
insert into @WidgetTransition values (2, 2, 12)
insert into @WidgetTransition values (2, 3, 12)

select *
from @Widget as Widget
  inner join @WidgetTransition as WidgetTransition
    on Widget.ID = WidgetTransition.WidgetID
  inner join
    ( select Widget.ID, max(WT.TransitionTypeID) as TrasitionTypeID
      from @Widget as Widget
        inner join
          ( select WidgetID, max(Cost) as Cost
            from @WidgetTransition
            group by WidgetID
          ) as MaxCost
          on Widget.ID = MaxCost.WidgetID
        inner join @WidgetTransition as WT
          on Widget.ID = WT.WidgetID and
             MaxCost.Cost = WT.Cost
        group by Widget.ID
    ) as MaxTransitionTypeID
    on Widget.ID = MaxTransitionTypeID.ID and
       WidgetTransition.TransitionTypeID = MaxTransitionTypeID.TrasitionTypeID
```